# Stacked bar chart with Largest value should be on the bottom, smallest value on the top http://jsfiddle.net/6bCBf/5/

Tags: angular, highcharts

We have a requirement in our project with high charts that is need to draw stacked bar chart with Largest value should be on the bottom, smallest value on the top.

Can you please provide your inputs/suggestions on this? For reference , Please review js fiddle example in the title

here we have 2 series and 3 stacked bars, for Jan month Sec(30) is greater than base (10) so sec series should be bottom of the stacked bar.

Tried to implement it with different approaches but could not able to get it.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. Add it to your question in text form, not to any external ressource

Answer (score 0):

There is no such built-in feature in Highcharts, but you can easily add an implementation for it. Using the `attr` method for manipulating each point's shape to rebuild stacks seems to be a good solution.

For example:

```
$(function() {
  function sortSeries(chart) {
    const series = chart.series;
    const yStart = chart.plotHeight;

    series[0].points.forEach((point, index) => {
      const points = series.map(s => s.points[index]);
      points.sort((p1, p2) => p2.y - p1.y);
      let lastY = 0;

      points.forEach((p, i) => {
        if (!p.series || !p.series.visible) {
          return false;
        }

        const newY = lastY ?
          lastY - p.shapeArgs.height :
          yStart - p.shapeArgs.height;

        lastY = newY;

        p.graphic.attr({
          y: newY
        });
        p.tooltipPos[1] = newY;
      });
    });
  }


  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      ...,
      events: {
        render: function() {
          sortSeries(this);
        }
      }
    },
    ...
  }, ...);
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ahp037xm/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render